# Outlook Addin duplicated attachment

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I have an Outlook addin written in unmanaged C++ which uses Outlook Object Model API.

The code copies Microsoft Office files (doc, docx, xls, xlsx, etc...) and PDF attachments to the temporary folder. Then the code manipulates  those files, and after that, it deletes the original attachment files and attaches the processed files.

Recently one of our customers reported duplicate attachment issue. I put some additional diagnostics, and here is what I see:

Here is the pseudo code of the diagnostic function:

```
bool COutlookAttachmentHelper::AreThereDuplicatesOnInput(long count)
```

{

```
   std::vector<std::wstring> vFileNames; 

   for(int i = count; i > 0; i--)
   {
        //get attachment filename
        .....
        // try to find it in the vector defined above
        std::vector<std::wstring>::iterator findIter = std::find(vFileNames.begin(), vFileNames.end(), strFileName);
        // if not found push it into the vector and return false
        // if found, write the filename to the log file, pop up the message
        // box, return true (cancel email).

   }
```

}

---

If the duplicates aren't found, then the code executes another loop to copy the files of interest to the temporary folder

the for loop is constructed the same way:

Here is what I see in my diagnostic log file:

---

Searching for the duplicates

**Some Word Document.DOC**

image003.gif

image002.png

image001.png

End of Searching for the duplicates

---

// Below is the output from the second loop

// I'm filtering out non Office and non PDF files

**Some Word Document.DOC**

**Some Word Document.DOC**

We can't reproduce the issue in our labs and none of the other customers report it.

Anyone have a clue?

Regards,

Michael

Comment: What is the message store where this message comes from?

Comment: Hi Dmitry. I do not exactly understand the question. Do you mean is message  coming from the Draft box, forwarded, etc...? Without that additional diagnostic check outlook will send the mail out with duplicate file without any errors. Intermittently, this doesn't happen  daily. Thanks.

Comment: I meant is that a PST store? Exchange mailbox? IMAP4 store? Or something else?

Comment: I see, they use Exchange.